# RSelenium count number of rows in a dynamic table

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I'm new to web scraping with RSelenium and currently working on extracting data from a website. It includes a dynamic table with pagination. I can access the element using,

```
all_companies <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="marketdata-tab1"]/div[1]/table')
```

Now what I want to do is get the number of rows to iteratively extract the content. So I used

```
all_companies$findElements(using = "css selector",'tr')
```

Which gives me the number of rows. My question is how can I use this to extract the value of each record? I have tried this with rvest. However it does not give the dynamic content of the table.

```
read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])%>%
html_nodes(xpath ='//*[@id="marketdata-tab1"]/div[1]/table')%>%
html_table()
```

Comment: what's the url and can you indicate a dynamic field whose value you were unable to retrieve?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the URL. I have to set some filters to update the table and then extract the rows.

Comment: It is just an idea. Could you try to download all the table and to make your table by the text rules.